# Java code not printing to console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this java code in eclipse. When I run it, I assume I should get something back in the console at the bottom of eclipse. This is not the case. The console at the bottom of eclipse is blank.

```
package com.veggiedogtreats.javacode;

public class doobeedoobeedo {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    while (x < 0) {
        System.out.println("Doo");
        System.out.println("Bee");
        x = x + 1;
    }
    if (x == 2 ) {
        System.out.print("Do");


    }

}

}
```

Comment: When is `1` ever less than `0`?

Comment: 1st april is tomorrow:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the while loop set to `x < 0`, it should be `x > 0`. The way you have it, it will never enter the while loop

Comment: Awesome that was it... Thanks for helping a noobie out :)

Answer (score 2):

Your while condition is wrong. it should read `while ( x > 0 )` instead of `while ( x < 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

Your program only prints to the console when x is less than zero and when x is 2.

x always has a value of 1.

```
int x = 1; // x is 1
while (x < 0) { // 1 is not less than zero, doesn't enter the loop
    System.out.println("Doo");
    System.out.println("Bee");
    x = x + 1;
}

if (x == 2 ) { // 1 is not two, doesn't enter the if
    System.out.print("Do");
}
```

Maybe you wanted something like this:

```
while (x < 0) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

your conditions are not satisfied and hence the `sysout` statements are not executed. Either change the initial value of `x` or the conditions so that the `sysout` statements are executed atleast once.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the conditional statements are true. 1 is not less than zero or equal to 2.